# reduction order method $xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2e^{2x}$, $y_1=1+x$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

reduction order method $xy''-(1+x)y'+y=x^2e^{2x}$, being $y_1=1+x$ a solution of the homogeneous equation.

I made y=u(1+x) and got $u''(x^2+x)-u'(x^2+1)=x^2e^{2x}$

Then i did $u'=w$ and obtained $w=\frac{e^{2x}x^2+c_1e^xx}{(x+1)^2}$, however $u=\int{w }dx$ will be a strange expression that will not give to the solution $y=c_1e^x+c_2(1+x)+\frac{e^{2x}(x-1)}{2}$.

Can you help me finding my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: why do you have three constants in the general solution $y?$

Comment: yes...i didn't saw it well...thanks user84413 and once again thanks @abel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your work so far looks correct, so to find $u=\displaystyle\int\frac{x^{2}e^{2x}+Cxe^x}{(x+1)^2}dx=\int\frac{(xe^x)(xe^x+C)}{(x+1)^2}dx$,

use integration by parts with $w=xe^x+C, dw=(x+1)e^x dx$ and $ dv=\frac{xe^x}{(x+1)^2}dx, \;v=\frac{e^x}{x+1}$

to get $\displaystyle u=(xe^{x}+C)\left(\frac {e^x}{x+1}\right)-\int e^{2x}dx=\frac{xe^{2x}+Ce^x}{x+1}-\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}+D$.

Then $y=(x+1)u$ should give the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

i will assume that your equation for $u,$ i.e. 
$(x^2+x)u^{\prime \prime} -(x^2+1)u^\prime= x^2e^{2x}
$ is correct. then $w = u^\prime$ satisfies $$ (x^2+x)w^\prime -(x^2+1)w= x^2e^x$$
verify that $$w = {Ax \over (x+1)^2}$$ solves the homogenous problem for $w.$ now we will use the variation of parameters that is assume $A$ is a function of $x$ to be determined.
$$w^\prime =  {A^\prime x \over (x+1)^2} + {A \over (x+1)^2} - {2Ax \over (x+1)^3}$$

putting this in the equation for $w$ gives 
$$ {A^\prime x^2 \over (x+1)} + {Ax \over (x+1)} - {2Ax^2 \over (x+1)^2} - {Ax(x^2+1) \over (x+1)^2} = x^2 e^{2x}$$  which simplifies to

$$ e^{-x}(A^\prime - A) = \frac{d(Ae^{-x})}{dx} = (x+1)e^x$$
so $$ Ae^{-x} = xe^x + C, w = {x(xe^{2x} + Ce^x) \over (x+1)^2 }$$

$$u =  \int  {  x(xe^{2x} + Ce^x) \over (x+1)^2 } dx $$ i hope i did not make any silly errors and you can do the integration by parts.